# Spring JPA Data Rest - Determine Which Repository Method Is Called

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

Is there a way to determine which repository method is being called?

I have a `Parent` entity that has a `OneToMany` annotation to a `Child` entity. In the HATEOAS documentation, I have the link which is `/parent/{id}/child` and can reach the children. I want to know what the method is that is returning the children so I can override it in the `ChildRepository`. I am having difficulty trying to determine that and have tried several ways to do so.

Is the `/parent/{id}/child` being called from the `ChildRepository` or is that being handled in the `ParentRepository`?

I have been at this for several hours and cannot find an answer on Google or SOF, maybe I someone can help me with the answer or ask the right question.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you need to implement a custom logic in Spring Data REST you can try to use:

1. [Projections and Excerpts](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#projections-excerpts), even in the output of repository query methods and for making DTO objects ([link](https://spring.io/blog/2016/05/03/what-s-new-in-spring-data-hopper#projections-on-repository-query-methods))
2. [Custom handlers](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#_writing_an_annotated_handler)
3. HATEOAS resource processors ([example1](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#_writing_an_annotated_handler), [example2](https://github.com/olivergierke/spring-restbucks/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springsource/restbucks/order/web/CoreOrderResourceProcessor.java), [example3](https://github.com/Cepr0/restvotes/blob/master/src/main/java/restvotes/rest/processor/AnyResourceProcessors.java))
4. [RepositoryRestControllers](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#customizing-sdr.overriding-sdr-response-handlers)

Comment: Thank you for the links, I was referring to something else. Apparently someone down voted my question for some unknown reason without telling me why.